# php не подключается к бд

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Код PHP,ошибка[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naUqJ.png)

Подскажите, что делать, php не подключается к бд

Comment: Перед `<br>` точку поставить нужно, или прописать апостроф `'` за тегом `<br>` _(перед точкой с запятой)_. На будущее - публикуйте код, а не его скриншот!

Comment: Тебе ведь интерпретатор четко указал тип ошибки, на какой строке ошибка, и даже символ который привел к ошибке.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'Не удалось подключиться к базе данных' . '<br>';
```

Забыл поставить точку и html теги в одинарные кавычки.